# Replace all files with identical hash

Tags: linux, bash, hashsum

I want to replace all files in a target path with the same name as original.file AND the same hash as orignal.file with new.file. What's the command to do this?

Say I have updated the contents of a file, and now I want all other copies of that file in a certain path to be updated as well.

In most cases the following code would work:

```
find /target_path/ -iname "original.file" -exec cp new.file '{}'
```

However if **original.file** is readme.txt for example, many unrelated files would be overwritten.

Comment: Why keep multiple copies of the same file if content never differ?  Can you use symbolic or hard links for this purpose?

Comment: I don't know Pacifika thoughts, but I happen to have multiple copies of same file in revision control. Hard or symbolic links are a no go, since different OS have different implementations of soft and hard links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This this will require a test to see if the checksums match before decide to run the `cp`, you will have to run a subshell as the `-exec` argument to find. This should do the job:

```
find /target_path/ -iname "original.file" -exec bash -c \
  '[[ $(md5sum "original.file") = $(md5sum "{}") ]] && cp "new.file" "{}"' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you if you can make all identical copies of files hard links. One way to do that is with [fdupes](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/): run `fdupes -L`. Then change files in place; this will preserve hard links.

If all you want to do is find a file by name and content or by name and hash, just add another condition to your `find` command.

```
find /target_path/ -iname "original.file" -exec cmp old.file {} -exec cp new.file {}
find /target_path/ -iname "original.file" \
                   -exec sh -c 'test "$(md5sum | sed "s/ .*//")" = "$1" <"$0"' {} "$(cat old.md5sum)" \
                   -exec cp new.file {}
```

You don't say what your application is; it may or may not help to involve [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), which [can detect identical files at different paths when doing remote synchronization](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/any-way-to-sync-directory-structure-when-the-files-are-already-on-both-sides/6518#6518).