# Is there a backup tool that recognized renamed/moved files/directories?

Tags: backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to sync directory structure when the files are already on both sides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/any-way-to-sync-directory-structure-when-the-files-are-already-on-both-sides)

I'm looking for a backup utility that recognizes files or folders in the source that have just been renamed or moved. Using `rsync` I get a lot of duplicates, when ideally it would reflect those operations on the target (like Microsoft's SyncToy does).

Example:

```
Source:        Target:
~/done/a       ~/done/a
~/done/b       ~/todo/b
~/todo-123/c   ~/todo/c
~/todo-123/d   ~/todo/d
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but pretty much any dedicated backup script on *nix should do this. Try `rdiff-backup` instead of manually rsync'ing, it should be able to deduce that files have been moved from the file dates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure rdiff-backup doesn't do this. Unison does.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, even if it's been a while ;-)