# Synchronize directory tree with deduplication?

Tags: rsync, synchronization, unison, deduplication

I have two Linux servers that have a large amount of data (1TB+) that need to be synchronized over a slow connection (100 KB/s).

A lot of the data overlaps, but are in different locations.

I would like some sort of rsync / unison tool where I can mirror the servers.

It would need to be more intelligent and identify if the file exists at the destination (possibly in another location with the same checksum). If it does, then it moves  the file locally on the destination server rather than copying the file from scratch from the source server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to sync directory structure when the files are already on both sides?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/any-way-to-sync-directory-structure-when-the-files-are-already-on-both-sides)

Answer (score 2):

May not be the answer you're looking for, but the best I can find from memory.

`-y, --fuzzy                 find similar file for basis if no dest file`

(sorry, should have mentioned, that is an rsync command/flag)

(additionally, I have NO IDEA how, specifically, it works)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did some [research](http://www.snowfrog.net/2011/03/03/fuzzy-rsync/) and `--fuzzy` only matches similar files in the same directory where similar is being defined as "identical size and modified time" or "similarly named".

Comment: Sorry.  Best I've got.  As deduplication goes, I use zfs, which is processor and/or memory expensive