# Pre-Cache unison

Tags: unison

I'm using my desktop and a single board cpu (Raspberry Pi 2 - 900 MHz) to sync two very large directories with large files. Often, the files are the same but the filenames are changed. [Unison is suggested here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6411/any-way-to-sync-directory-structure-when-the-files-are-already-on-both-sides) for that purpose, which I've used to good effect for smaller directories / files.

However, waiting for the single board to hash the files takes a very long time.

Is it possible to pre-cache the hashes so that I could run it overnight periodically with cron?

My attempt:

```
# Roots of the synchronization
label = Precaches Media Server
auto = true
root = /media/Files
root = /media/Files
```

However, syncing against itself causing a locking issue

```
Contacting server...
Looking for changes
Fatal error: Warning: the archives are locked.
```

Comment: What you might do is to make a second mount. First create (as an example) /media/Files2, then mount via `sudo mount -o bind /mediaFiles /media/Files2`, so now you have two mountpoints on the same device. In your configuration replace the second line by `/media/Files2`. Unison then sees two different folders with identical contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can fool Unison by giving it two views of the same tree that it doesn't recognize as being the same tree, through a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount).

```
mkdir /media/Files-bind
bindfs -n /media/Files /media/Files-bind
unison /media/Files /media/Files-bind </dev/null
```

I'm not sure if it actually precomputes the hashes in a way that can be used for another pair of archives, but it will compute the hashes of the local files twice.

I suspect that the only good solution would be to patch Unison to add the functionality you want.