# How to use rmlint to merge two large folders?

Tags: shell, duplicate, deduplication, duplicate-files, rmlint

In exploring options to merge two folders, I've come across a very powerful tool known as [rmlint](https://github.com/sahib/rmlint). It has some useful [documentation](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (and [Gentle Guide](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html)).

I have a scenario that I previously mentioned and to which I received some great answers:

[How to merge two folders so as to remove identical files from one, while keeping checksummed differentials?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/628685/47012)

I was leaning towards the `rdfind` answer, but as I was researching it a bit I stumbled upon `rmlint` and found the developer's [discussion](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cautions.html) on duplicate isolation to be quite elucidating.

While reviewing all of this I found a couple interesting arguments:
`--merge-directories --honour-dir-layout`

I thus tried an incantation as follows:

```
rmlint -T "bi,bl,df,dd" --progress --merge-directories --honour-dir-layout A B
```

Unfortunately the saved command that I'm to execute is rather enormous given my large scenario and haven't really been able to isolate a manageable smaller subset thus far to test on to establish any degree of confidence before firing this up.  I tried to find a way to do a trial run so it might print out what it would be doing vs showing it to me in a script so as to emulate the actions that would be taken, but I'm not finding this option (maybe I'm just bleary eyed and overlooking it?).

I therefore thought I could and should pose a question here to this end:

**Has anyone had any success at merging duplicate data sets with `rmlint` and, if so, what arguments would you suggest to merge two folders such that the goals of my earlier question may be reasonably met?**

*To briefly restate: The ultimate goal is to get everything that is unique to B into A, while deleting everything in B that is already present in A and anything that has a data contents conflict (ie, non-unique contents) between A and B then leave in both for manual compare such that it will be relatively easy to find these in B after after execution.*

Answer (score 1):

Indeed `rmlint` seems better suited for the task than `rdfind`. I like that it outputs a shell script, which you can examine to verify that it doesn't propose to do something you didn't really intend.

For your use case, I was drawn to the section of the manual that talks about [Flagging original directories](https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#flagging-original-directories), since you clearly have an "original" directory and a "duplicate" one.

This example looks like you could use it as a starting point:

```
# Find all files on /media/portable that can be safely deleted:
$ rmlint --keep-all-tagged --must-match-tagged /media/portable // ~
```

Note that your original directory comes *after* the `//`, which I found a bit surprising (by default the tool seems to prefer keeping the file from the *earlier* argument). So `rmlint --keep-all-tagged --must-match-tagged B // A`.

(Note: I don't have personal experience with `rmlint`, I'm just going by the documentation)